# Formatting the datein html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

is it possible to format the date in my html file?
Response I am receiving from `item.starts_at`

`starts_at: '2018-01-10 07:28:00'`.
I would like to display this as **Jan 10**

Comment: Just bind somewhere in your view sth like this `<%= item.starts_at.strftime('%b %d')%>`

Comment: @TashiDendup why don't you post it as an answer so it can get upvoted, marked as answered etc?

Comment: Please accept my answer if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
<%= item.starts_at.strftime('%b %d') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`I18n.l(Date.today, format: :short)` is what you are looking for, Rails includes these localization formats, more details: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml#L3